# How correctly ask first child in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, onclick, css-selectors

My code:

```
news_divs[i].innerHTML= content.substr(0,this.config.head_length)+"...<div style='display:none'>"+content+"</div>";
news_divs[i].onclick = function(){var child=this.getElementByTagName('div')[0];child.style="display:block;"}
```

But it return error in last string.
Error text:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function news_div.js:9

news_divs.(anonymous function).onclick
```

I tested:

```
news_divs[i].onclick = function(){var child=this.firstChild;child.style="display:block;
```

and

```
news_divs[i].onclick = function(){var child=this.children[0];child.style="display:block;
```

but always get this error.

When I writed (for Example):

```
news_divs[i].onclick = function(){console.log('test')}
```

It was work.

`news_div` isn't undefind.

I think I have error because my ask isn't correct.
How do this correct?

Comment: where is "i" being set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `getElement s ByTagName`, with an `s`, and using  addEventListener will give `this` the right value, also note the way the style is set

```
news_divs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var child = this.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; 
    child.style.display = "block";
}, false);
```